# Android Studio 1.4 Rendering Problems In New Drawer Template

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationview

I have just updated to Android Studio 1.4. I have created a new project with the target SDK set to Marshmellow. When I create a new Navigation Drawer Activity, I can run the activity on a virtual device just fine. However none of the XML layouts display in the preview pane.

Here are the errors:
activity_main.xml:

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes   The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find bool resource matching value 0x7F090006 (resolved name: abc_config_showMenuShortcutsWhenKeyboardPresent) in current configuration.   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:841)   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getBoolean(BridgeResources.java:610)   at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.setShortcutsVisibleInner(MenuBuilder.java:790)   at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.(MenuBuilder.java:227)   at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenu.(NavigationMenu.java:34)   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:99)   at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:92)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard  Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme (8 similar errors not shown)

app_bar_main.xml:

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes   Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme (8 similar errors not shown)

content_main.xml:

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes   Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme (8 similar errors not shown)

nav_header_main.xml:

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Couldn't resolve resource @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark (3 similar errors not shown) Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme (2 similar errors not shown)

Since its mentioning missing styles, here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I'm new to Android development and when the default templates are throwing errors at you like this, it isn't the best way to be introduced to a new framework :(

Even an explanation as to what is going wrong would help. Thanks.

Comment: Had the same thing happen when I tried making a new one today. I unfortunately did not investigate too closely. But I think you'll be able to fix it by doing one of the following. 

1. Got to the Build Menu and select Rebuild.
2. Close the project and open it again.

I haven't had the issue show up even after making several new test projects.

Comment: Yeah the issue appears to have gone away for me, I wasn't sure what I did that fixed it so I left this question open, but a rebuild was probably it!

Answer (score 1):

Go to app -> res -> values -> style.xml

and then add the word "Base" in front of the parent.

for example, before adding the keyword "Base"

parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

after adding the keyword

parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

for more information please refer to [this link](https://youtu.be/Ox7TvRJR_Ds?t=57s)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue, and I think the best solution is to click on the "Automatically add all missing attributes" link. Then, everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just opened sdk manager and updated 'Android Support Repository' to version 24. This worked for me.

Android Support Repository can be found below in the 'Extras' category.

sdk manager default path is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

[Here is the screenshot of sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdzj1.png)

If still it does not work, try updating 'Android Support Library' 'Google Play Services' and 'Google Repository' too.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity class must extend `AppCompatActivity`